# Stackplot using list of dictionary values (Python 3.x)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, matplotlib

I am trying to make a stackplot from a dictionary where the value is a list of floats between 0 and 1 and the index of the value in the list is the time (t1, t2, ...tn) of measurement. All keys have the same number of values. For example:

```
a = {1:[0.3,0.5,0.7], 2:[0.4,0.6,0.8], 5:[0.1,0.15,0.20]}
```

so that at t2: `a[1] = 0.5, a[2] = 0.6, and a[5] = 0.15`, and so on at the other indices of the list of values.

I'm going for a stackplot like the one [here](http://glowingpython.blogspot.com/2015/04/stacked-area-plots-with-matplotlib.html) with the indices of the value list on the x-axis and the value of a[i] at that index on the y-axis , but can't figure out how to adapt that code or the [matplotlib example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/stackplot_demo.html) to a dictionary.

**Python version:** 3.4

**Error (for both my data and toy data set):**
`TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''`

Suggestions?

Comment: The syntax of your dictionary is invalid.

Comment: that is an incorrect dictionary syntax. a dictionary is written like `a = {1:[0.3,0.5,0.7], 2:[0.4,0.6,0.8]}`

Comment: Noted, that was a typo in the example. Not a problem I encountered in my true dictionary.

Comment: Am I right in assuming that you don't actually need the keys of `a`?

Comment: @jojo Right -- the keys of a are just identifiers, so the only time I'd use them is in building the legend.

Comment: I'm getting the TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''.

Comment: @jojo Both -- and I'm using Python 3.4.

Comment: In this case try my answer with `fnx = lambda : np.random.randint(5, 50, 10).values.astype(np.float64)` which enforces the elements to be actual floating point numbers.

Comment: @jojo then I get AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'values'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE** - The error you are getting is because matplotlib is somehow not happy with the view you are getting from `dict.values()`. Note that this is only a problem of python 3.x as for python 2.x `dict.values()` returns a list. You can simply avoid this problem by converting the view into a normal list, so `list(dict.values())`.

Here is the [matplotlib example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/stackplot_demo.html) using a `dict`, working for both python 2.x and 3.x:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fnx = lambda : np.random.randint(5, 50, 10).astype(np.float64)
d = {i: v for i, v in enumerate(np.row_stack((fnx(), fnx(), fnx())))}
# d looks basically like your a
x = range(len(d[0]))
y = list(d.values()) # d.values() returns a view in python 3.x
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.stackplot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: range() replaced xrange() in Python 3+

Comment: Even once I remove .values, I still get the TypeError. Would it matter that some of the decimal numbers I use are particularly long?

Comment: @bradi note that Decimal type [is not supported](http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/type-error-with-python-3-2-and-version-1-1-1-of-matplotlib-numpy-error-td38784.html) so you should be fine if you convert your dictionary `a` to contain only floats.

Comment: @bradi to convert all the entries in `a` to floats: `a = {i: map(lambda x: float(x), a[i]) for i in a}`

Comment: @bradi The issue is that dict.values() is a [view](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views) in python 3.x. This is what was causing the error. `y = list(d.values())` will get you there (finally :P).

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you want to achieve, but if I understood you, this should work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a = {1:[0.3,0.5,0.7], 2:[0.4,0.6,0.8], 5:[0.1,0.15,0.20]}
plt.stackplot(a.keys(),a.values())
```

[image]